# webview.goBack() method doesnt invoke shouldOverrideUrlLoading method

Tags: android, webview

I want every page loaded in my app go through the url override method ( where i do some html modifications ). How can i achieve this?.

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    // do some html modifcations (myhtml)
    view.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, myhtml, "text/html", "utf-8", url);
    return false;
}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web1.canGoBack()) {
        web1.goBack(); // go back 1 step
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: I'm also interested in the answer of this question.

Answer (score 1):

on page finished method you will get the url  and you can reload the url

```
       @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            _dialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,String description, String failingUrl) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            try{
                _dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(Showwebviewlatestnews.this, "NO Internet Connection Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to return `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` **true**
Here is an explanation:-

**True if the host application wants to leave the current WebView and handle the url itself, otherwise return false.** [Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String))

So this should do the trick,

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    // do some html modifcations (myhtml)
    view.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, myhtml, "text/html", "utf-8", url);
    return true;
}
```

And handle `backPressed()` like -

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webview != null && webview.canGoBack()) {
        webview.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

//Replace this

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web1.canGoBack()) {
    web1.goBack(); // go back 1 step
    return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);}
```

With

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web1.canGoBack()) {
    web1.goBack(); // go back 1 step
    web1.goBack(); 
    return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);}
```